# Update vb.net MS Access DB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, updates

I've been working on a mini inventory software but im having problems with the edit function. I have look everywhere and seen multiple example with no answer that seem to work. I'm super new to vb.net programming so bear with me xD

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bAdd.Click

        If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then myConnection.Open()
            Dim st As String = "UPDATE [ListProducts] SET [NameProduct] = '" & NamPro1.Text & "', [PricePro] = '" & PriPro1.Text & "'WHERE [ID] = '" & InventorioA.InventorioGrid.SelectedCells(0).Value & "'"

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(st, myConnection)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            myConnection.Close()
            InventorioA.fill()
            Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

If it helps my DB has multiple tables and that specific table is called `[ListProducts]` having 3 colums in it been

```
[ID] [NameProduct] [PricePro]
```

I dont know the solution but I do get this error if it helps

> [An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occured in mscorlib.ddl]
>
> [Additional information:Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection.]

Comment: When you debug this, where are you accessing an out-of-range index?  I suspect it's this: `SelectedCells(0)`.  If `SelectedCells` is empty, then there would be no first element in that collection.

Comment: @David yup that line. I have 2 different forms one is called InventorioA and the other is InventorioB in A is where the data grid is located and i call it in form B.

Comment: Well, regardless of what you're trying to build, the error itself is fairly straightforward once you understand what it means.  Basically, the `SelectedCells` collection is empty.  And you can't reference the first item (or any item) in an empty collection.  Basically, you can't use the first selected cell if no cell is selected.  So you're going to want to adjust your logic to handle that.  Maybe use an `If` condition to check if a cell is selected before trying to use it.

Comment: @David thz ill give it a try.